# length of Array of Objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to calculate how many records hold an Array of Objects . here's my code:

```
public class PoS {
    int id;
    String name;
    double pos_gps_lat;
    double pos_gps_long;

    public PoS(int id, String name,double pos_gps_lat, double pos_gps_long) {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.pos_gps_lat=pos_gps_lat;
        this.pos_gps_long=pos_gps_long;

    }
}
```

I added only one (1) record as fellow

```
PoS pos[]=new PoS[1];   // updated as requested in comments
pos[0]=new PoS(1,"test",12.123456, 12.123456);
```

But i get 4 as a result :

```
  System.out.printf(pos.length);
```

Question 1:
How i can get the number of records and **not** the number of elements that an Array of Objects  contains?

Question 2:
I'm going to use over 10 K records, is Array of Objects the best option in term of performance?

Comment: An array does not count the number of elements inside it. Use a `List` to get that functionality out of the box (using the `size` method). Otherwise you have to count the array elements yourself.

Comment: If your print statement be really showing you _4_, then it is because you initialized that array with a size of four.  It has nothing to do with the number of fields in the `PoS` class.

Comment: No, it's initialized with 1

Comment: @Nizar the only way `System.out.printf(pos.length);` prints `4` is when you initialize the array as `pos = new Pos[4];`.

Comment: @f1sh No, it's     PoS pos[]=new PoS[1];

Comment: Prove it by showing your entire code, from start to end. (You'll fail, because what you're saying is incorrect)

Comment: @  kumesana code updated

Comment: No. I said entire code, from start to end. You've shown one line. Try and look up where your program starts. What you need to show starts there. Now figure out where your program ends. You need to show everything from the start to the end

Comment: This is not your full code then. `(new PoS[1]).length` cannot be `4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array has a fixed length, and `.length` gives you that length (which is `4` in your case, based on the output you got). The array instance has no method that returns the number of array indices that actually reference a non-null value.

You'll have to maintain a separate `int` counter in order to obtain this information. This counter will also let you know in which index of the array you can assign new data.

If you want to know the actual number of elements, you can use an `ArrayList` instead of an array. The `size()` method will tell you how many elements were added to the `List`.

As to whether or not an array of 10000 objects is the best option, that would depend on whether you are going to fill all/most of that array, and whether or not you'll never need to store more than 10000 objects. Using an `ArrayList` will give you more flexibility.

Comment: tou can also explain about performance issue like size allocation on array vs list

Comment: But the problem that i have is i have to calculate the size each time because i have to remove a record after some calculation.

Comment: @Nizar in that case, use an `ArrayList`. You cannot remove an element from an array. You can only set it to `null` (which may leave a "hole" in your array) or overwrite it with a different element of the array. `ArrayList`, which is backed by an array, already takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Array sizes are immutable once created, so unless you want to use a mutable `Collection` such as a `List`, the `length` property will give you the size with which the array has been initialized.

Therefore, chances are your array has been initialized as `new Pos[4]`, and you've only populated element at index `0` (but the `length` is still `4`).

However since Java 8 you can also use a slightly longer construct to return the size of the non-null elements in your array:

`Arrays.stream(pos).filter(Objects::nonNull).count()`

The latter does the following:

- Provides a stream of the array's elements
- Filters by static method reference `Objects::nonNull` i.e. only non-null objects
- Provides a `long` terminal operation, counting the filtered elements (e.g. in your case, probably just the one)

Note that, while syntactically concise, this operation has a higher cost than referencing a `length` property, as it does iterate over the array elements under the hood.

Answer (score -3):

Answer to Question1, do you try this?

```
 Object[] arrayOfObjects = new Object[2];
int length = Array.getLength(arrayOfObjects );
```

Note that its a general mode, you addapt it to your code.

Comment: what is Array.getLength? What class is that?

Comment: import java.util.Arrays Might be

Comment: The getLength() method of Array class returns the length of the specified array object, as an int.

Comment: @MalavanRockzz java.util.Arrays does not have a `getLength` method.

Comment: He means `java.lang.reflect.Array`, which has a static method `getLength(Object)`

Comment: @ernest_k that simply returns `argument.length`, which is what OP's code already does, making this answer useless. Also it makes use of native reflection code, which should not be used unless it can't be avoided.

Comment: @f1sh I agree on that. Was just posting an answer to your question :)

Comment: Array.getLength()  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#getLength(java.lang.Object)

Comment: About performance, Arrays are faster than ArrayList. Had it been you know the definite amount of data to be entered, say 10k, initializing the array with the size would have been better. I suggest you go for ArrayList as the performance issue won't be that noticeable...